# How to validate and return access and refresh tokens after user.save()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt, django-validation

I'm verifying the user OTP to change password and after change password I'm unable to create access and refresh token using JWT ,

Normally when user get log in I use following method `MyTokenObtainPairView` which return both access and refresh token with all other stuff to `UserSerializerWithToken`.

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data
        for k, v in serializer.items():
            data[k] = v

        return data


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

I coppied similar appraoch to return `UserSerializerWithToken` after set_password and user.save()

UserSerializerWithToken is

```
class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id',
                  'isAdmin',
                  'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

and the problematic function is

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def reset_password(request):
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    otp_to_verify = data['otp']
    new_password = data['password']
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        if otp_to_verify == user.otp:
            if new_password != '':
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save() # here password gets changed 
                return Response(serializer.data) # 
            else:
                message = {
                'detail': 'Password cant be empty'}
                return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        message = {
            'detail': 'Something went wrong'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I receive the toke but not getting access and refresh toke to use it to login next time. I'm assuming user.save() dosnt create refresh and access token here. Can anybody identify why this is happening and how to fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user.save()` does not create the tokens

`token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)`
`return str(token.access_token)`

These lines create the token.

In my opinion, you dont need the serializer here.

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def reset_password(request):
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    otp_to_verify = data['otp']
    new_password = data['password']
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        otp_to_verify == user.otp
        if new_password != '':
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save() # here password gets changed 
            token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            response = { "refresh_token": str(token),
                         "access_token": str(token.access_token)
                       }
            return Response(response)
        else:
            message = {
                'detail': 'Password cant be empty'}
            return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        message = {
            'detail': 'Something went wrong'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: thanks Arun , it's generating the token but not updating the user with new refresh and access token, Can u update this functions so it can also update the user with token

Comment: what do you mean by update the user with new token?
Your front end application would have to update the token in their session.

Comment: were you able to get it working?

Comment: Yes there was problem in front end

Comment: I wasnt passing the password correctly in inputs onChange

Comment: And there was no need to generate the tokens after save

Answer (score 1):

When you save user, you can make a post request:

```
 access_url = config('BASE_API_URL') + 'token/'
 access_response = requests.post(access_url, data=data)
 access_token = access_response.json().get('access')
 refresh_token = access_response.json().get('refresh')
```

Then return,

```
 return Response(
    {"access_token": access_token,
     "refresh_token" : refresh_token,
     "additional_data": messege},
     status=status.HTTP_200_OK
  )
```